# How are strings stored in a GO array?

Tags: arrays, string, go

Following the tour of GO, I encountered the following code:

```
var a [2]string
a[0] = "Hello"
a[1] = "World"
```

So, an array's length is inmutable and set when the array is declared. But then you can store strings of any size in it.

Why can you do this?

Answer (score 1):

In Go, a string is a fixed-length struct containing a length and a pointer to a byte array.

So `var a [2]string` allocates an array with space for two such structs.

`a[0] = "Hello"` allocates another array to store "Hello", and puts a pointer to this, and a length into `a[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are like read-only slices of bytes. So the reason this code works is because the array need only allocate space for a pointer and some metadata (the length of the string).

See the section on Strings here (at the bottom):

https://blog.golang.org/slices